# Detect when View within Listview item is visible

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a Listview whose items contain several custom Views which perform animations. The problem is that these animations occur even when that item is only partially shown, so if the View is at the bottom of that item, say, then the animation happens too quickly off screen and you don't see it.

Is there a callback or similar I can hook into to detect when this View within the Listview item actually comes on to the screen itself and then run the animation at that time?

Comment: Set a scroll listener on your list view and check for firstVisibleItem in onScroll()

Comment: The problem is that it is the View itself that needs to know when it will be shown on screen. I can set a scroll listener but that will only return the whole list item. I need to animate when the portion of the list item containing that animating View is just scrolled onto the screen.

Comment: Without all of your views being the same height I'm not sure how to do this. If your views are the same height you can check current scroll position vs viewHeight*viewPosition

Answer (score 0):

Try using listview methods `getLastVisiblePosition()` and `getFirstVisiblePosition()`.